# how to compare enum value in sql statment?

Tags: postgresql

I have a enum type ( sample below) , which is saved in the product table . I did a search online but couldn't make it work on my sql query, I would like to do a case statement and compare type is equal to electronics , but i'm not sure how to do with the enum? any thoughts.
also, there might be null values for restocking and shipping colum, i would like to check if those
values are not null , before calculating total price . is there a succinct  way to do this?

```
select name, 
 type ,
       CASE type 
           WHEN type= 'electronics' THEN  price * restocking * shipping
           WHEN 'furniture' THEN do something else
       END product_totalAmount
```

```
CREATE TYPE enum_ProductConfig_productType AS ENUM (
    'furniture',
    'electronics',
    ...);
```

product table

```
id | name    | type           | price  |  restocking | shipping
1. | desktop | electronics    | 298    |  null       | 45
```

Comment: What is `WHEN 'PG'` meant to do? Is that one of your enum values?

Comment: You should use either `CASE type WHEN 'electronics' THEN …` or `CASE WHEN type = 'electronics' THEN …`, but not a mix of them.

Comment: @Bergi - thanks. I edited the question.  I have one more follow up question if don't mind.

Comment: "*i would like to check if those values are not null , before calculating total price*" - and what do you want to happen if they're null? Anyway, `COALESCE` is usually the most succinct way of dealing with them.

Comment: @Bergi - thanks, only include the values in the calculation  if they are not null

Comment: Then you'll want `price * COALESCE(restocking, 1) * COALESCE(shipping, 1)`

Comment: if you use the syntax  `CASE type ...`then you just put the value to match in `WHEN ... THEN` so `WHEN type= 'electronics' ` should be  `WHEN 'electronics' `